# What is the image of the unit disc $\{z:|z-z_0|<1\}$ under the inversion $\frac{1}{z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I can find the image of the unit disc under simple transformations like $z+a$; the image would be $\{z:|z-z_0-a|<1\}$, the disc has been translated by a distance $a$.

However I don't even know where to begin with finding the image under $\frac{1}{z}$.

Comment: Have you tried using polar coordinates?

Comment: No, how would I do that? Let $z=re^{i\theta}$? So $\frac{1}{z}=re^{-i\theta}$? Then what would I do?

Comment: @user330513 Careful: $\;z=re^{i\theta}\implies\frac1z=\frac1re^{-i\theta}\;,\;\;r\neq0\;$

Answer (score 1):

Let us agree on the term "inversion" for $z \rightarrow Z=\dfrac{1}{z}$

(even if true inversion would normaly be $Z=\dfrac{1}{\bar{z}}$).

The answer is that the image of the disk $D(z_0,1)$:

- 1) is a disk if $|z_0| \neq 1$.
- 2) is a half-plane delimited by a straight line passing through the origin if $|z_0| =1$.

Proof: Let us consider the case 1) with the supplementary condition $|z_0| > 1$.

All the following transformations are equivalent:

First, take the square of the initial condition $|z-z_0|^2 < 1$

Expand under the form

$$(z-z_0)(\overline{z-z_0})<1 \ \Longleftrightarrow \ |z|^2-z\bar{z_0}-\bar z z_0 +|z_0|^2<1$$

Replace $z$ by $1/Z$ (its transform), which gives after simplification:

$$1-z_0Z-\bar{z_0}\bar{Z}+|z_0|^2|Z|^2<|Z|^2$$

Setting $a=|z_0|^2-1$, we can, after division by $a$, assumed $\neq 0$ (we are in case 1)), write the previous expression under the form:

$$\dfrac{1}{a}-\dfrac{z_0}{a}Z-\dfrac{\bar{z_0}}{a}\bar{Z}+Z \bar{Z}<0$$

or, due to the definition of $a$:

$$\left(Z-\dfrac{\bar{z_0}}{a}\right)\left(\bar{Z}-\dfrac{z_0}{a}\right)<\dfrac{1}{a^2}$$

i.e.,

$$\left|Z-\dfrac{\bar{z_0}}{a}\right|^2<\dfrac{1}{a^2} \ \ \ (*)$$

Thus, in an equivalent way, $Z$ belongs to the disk with center

$$\dfrac{\bar{z_0}}{a} \ \ \text{and radius} \ \ \dfrac{1}{a} \ \ \ \ (*)$$

The other subcase $|z_0|<1$ can be treated in the same way.

For the limit case, $|z_0|=1$, it suffices to make $|z_0|\rightarrow 1$ in (*): then $a \rightarrow 0$; therefore the radius and the center $\rightarrow \infty$, and we find a halfplane.

Here is an example:  we have taken some thousand of points uniformly distributed in a first disk centered in $z_0=3/2+i$ with radius $1$ (red stars). The images of these points (blue stars) are all situated in the disk with center $2/3-i 4/9$ and radius $4/9$ in conformity with (*) ; note that they are no longer uniformly distributed.

[image]

Comment: @user330513 I have corrected an error at the end in the radius which is $1/a$ and not $1/\sqrt{a}$. Moreover, I have made a graphical example (Matlab programmation).

Comment: @user330513 Can you say at least if you understand what I have done.